# Hide public Property when exposed through web service

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to prevent a property from being exposed via my WCF web service. I tried adding the XmlIgnore attribute bug that didn't work. We are using .NET 3.5. WCF.

This doesn't work:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string S1 { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public string S2NotExposed { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark your class with the [DataContract] attribute from the [DataContractAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) , then mark only the properties you want to expose with the [DataMember] attribute from the [DataMemberAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx).

Comment: there must be a way without having to tack on DataMember, that's obsolete now anyway...unnecessary in newer versions of WCF