# .NET Web Service - How to make properties invisible

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have an ASP.NET (.asmx) Web Service project that has a method like:

```
 public int GetData(Data d);
```

And Data class has properties:

```
  public class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I want the "Id" property to be seen by client, but not the "Name" property. They all have to be public because inner logic of the application need these properties public.

So how can I set the "Name" property invisible to the client **without changing its public accesser, and without making private get, private set?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can prevent serialisation with the XmlIgnore tag, the proxy classes generated by the client won't contain the property Name.

```
public class Data
{
  public int Id{get;set;}

  [XmlIgnore()]
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are discovering a great reason to use DTOs. A DTO (data transfer object) is what you want to show the outside world.

So in your example your `Data` object is your domain object, which you use inside of your application, but it contains properties you don't want to give to anyone else. You then have your `DataDto` object, which is the externally exposed object that you share with other people.

You would then map from `Data` to `DataDto` before you send the information out and if necessary, you would map the other way if you received a DataDto in a request. (Or use a tool like AutoMapper).

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DataDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: DTO stands for data transfer object http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: I already know DTO logic but in my case, it has performance penalties while mapping since my class to be converted has about 100 properties. The Data class in the question is just a sample.

Comment: @Sohnee while your question has been answered, please remember the DTO pattern, it might come in useful in the future :)

Comment: @MattDavey, thanks for the support for my answer, having written a lot of API integrations, I've found DTOs are great for protecting API consumers from unnecessary change.

Comment: oops I meant to @Ahmet Altun to remember DTO pattern.. Sohnee I think yours should have been the winning answer :)

Comment: @MattDavey - thanks very much! People don't like DTOs until they've used them. When you "think" about them up front they sound like a lot of wasted work and duplication, but actually they aren't! You shouldn't have to pollute your domain objects with attributes and your service consumers shouldn't have to change just because you added a field to a domain object.

Comment: @Sohnee completely agree! A DTO is not simply an object to transfer data across a wire - it's also a crucial element in defining the **interface** between layers. It's that well defined interface which leads to low coupled, highly cohesive, easy to maintain projects :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>public class Data
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; private set; }
    }</strike>

I've never done this...but this could work? (after @ChrisBD answer)

```
public class Data
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; internal set; }
}
```

Comment: NO. It is not. Because if property is "private set", then inner application can't set it neither.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use WCF, when at least one property/member is marked with `[DataMember]` attribute then all marked are serialized and all othe are not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623639/hide-public-property-when-exposed-through-web-service

Answer (score 0):

Use the internal access modifier as this limits access only to items within the same assembly.

```
public class Data
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  internal string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use,

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
public string Name
{
    get;
    set;
}
```